# Need to make a login window with username and password in C# but when i introduce an incorrect username or password i get an error

Tags: c#

**when i introduce an incorrect username or password i get this error:**
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string inserteduser = textBox1.Text;
        string insertedpassword = textBox2.Text;
        List<User> user = new List<User>();
        user.Add(new User { username = "Michael", password = "1990" });
        user.Add(new User { username = "Diana", password = "1234" });
        int userlenght = user.Capacity/2;

        for (int i = 0; i <= userlenght; i++)
        {
            if (user[i].username == inserteduser && user[i].password == insertedpassword)
                MessageBox.Show("Login succesfull");
            if  (i == userlenght)
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");**It never get's here**
        }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `i <= userlenght` instead use `i < user.Count` in your `for` loop. `Capacity` is not the same as `Length` or `Count` The `List` collection is a zero index based collection. The first entry has an index of "0". You have  a count of two entries in the `List` so the last index is `List.Count - 1`

Comment: Please mark the line which gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things you could be doing differently:

- Move the List out to class level so that it only gets populated once.
- Use `user.Count` and < (less than) in your loop.
- Declare a bool to determine if login was successful.

All together, that might look more like:

```
private List<User> user = new List<User>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    user.Add(new User { username = "Michael", password = "1990" });
    user.Add(new User { username = "Diana", password = "1234" });
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inserteduser = textBox1.Text;
    string insertedpassword = textBox2.Text;

    bool success = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <user.Count; i++)
    {
        if (user[i].username == inserteduser && user[i].password == insertedpassword)
        {
            success = true;
            break;
        }                                    
    }
    if (success)
    {
        label1.Text = "Passed!";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Username or password is incorrect";
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments:
Do not use i <= userlenght instead use i < user.Count in your for loop. Capacity is not the same as Length or Count The List collection is a zero index based collection. The first entry has an index of "0". You have a count of two entries in the List so the last index is List.Count - 1.

But to make this all less verbose and easy to understand you could simply use `LINQ` and do this:

```
var success = user.Any(x => x.username == inserteduser && x. password == insertedpassword);

var message = success ? "Login succesfull" : "Username or password is incorrect";
MessageBox.Show(message);
```